# split attribute using ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, splitting, string

I have a long string in one attribute. I want to be able to extract a small portion of it into a new attribute. 
This is an example of the attribute:

"< html xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">   < meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" > < /head > < body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;" > < table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px" > < tr style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:#9CBCE2" > < td >Fly500< /td > < /tr > < tr > < td > < table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px" > < tr > < td >Name< /td > < td >Fly500< /td > < /tr > < tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3" > < td >Notes< /td > < td >< /td > < /tr >  < tr > < td >Source< /td > < td >< /td > < /tr > < tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3" > 
< td >Duplicate< /td > < td > < Null >< /td > < /tr > < tr > < td > Type < /td > < td > **Wildlife Sensitive Area**< /td > < /tr > < tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3" > < td >Start_Date< /td > < td >May 1< /td > < /tr > < tr > < td >End_Date< /td > < td

In bold is what I want to extract. I tried splitting using Right and Left, But it is not always located at the same number of characters from either side. What I would need to do is take everything right of < td > Type < /td > and extract what is between the next  "< td > < /td >" area.

Comment: Is all that text in one field?

Comment: Yes, and there is more I just cut it so it was faster to go through.

Comment: Looks like a parsing HTML question with a HTMLParser module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work if it looks exactly like your example. Use Python parser:

```
def extract(textfield):
    return textfield.split('Type')[-1].split('< td >')[1].split('<')[0].strip()
```

Call the function on your new field with:

```
extract(!Textfield!)
```

Change !Textfield! to match the name of your field.

You will very likely need to adapt the code, take a look at [Common string operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), for example split and strip. This: `[0], [-1]` is indexing, see [Python Lists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm).

Example in python console:

```
text = '"< html xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"> < meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" > < /head > < body style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;overflow:auto;background:#FFFFFF;" > < table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px" > < tr style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:#9CBCE2" > < td >Fly500< /td > < /tr > < tr > < td > < table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px" > < tr > < td >Name< /td > < td >Fly500< /td > < /tr > < tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3" > < td >Notes< /td > < td >< /td > < /tr > < tr > < td >Source< /td > < td >< /td > < /tr > < tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3" > < td >Duplicate< /td > < td > < Null >< /td > < /tr > < tr > < td > Type < /td > < td > Wildlife Sensitive Area< /td > < /tr > < tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3" > < td >Start_Date< /td > < td >May 1< /td > < /tr > < tr > < td >End_Date< /td > < td'
def extract(textfield):
    return textfield.split('Type')[-1].split('< td >')[1].split('<')[0].strip()

extract(text)
'Wildlife Sensitive Area'
```

Comment: I ran into problem just like yours and decided to create a usable library (still developing).
It extracts stream, so it can extract data if your data is to big to put in to memory.
So, if you've ever needed an alternative: https://github.com/Mandelag/util/tree/master/StreamExtractor